# How to replace default values in the text field using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium

I know how to send keys into a blank field as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://www.aircanada.com/en/'
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_id('departure1').send_keys('28/03/2014')
```

However, since the field already has default value 'DD/MM/YYYY', how can I replace that field value with my value (i.e., '28/03/2014')

Comment: What is the real URL? (it's not https://www.example.com).

Comment: @barak manos please have a look at my edited question

Comment: are you referring to `Departure Date` field?

Comment: have you tried `browser.find_element_by_id('departure1').clear();`?

Comment: @barakmanos Did YOU see real website?

Comment: @Amith No sucess really, it could not replace the field. Instead, it just add the new date after the default values

Comment: @neha: Yes, posted an answer below and tested it.

Comment: You're welcome, and a ticket to Canada would be a nice gesture to conclude this one :) ... And of course, you can accept the answer by clicking the V next to it...

Comment: @barak manos I really flipped a coin honestly once, and user1177636 won, sorry that I could not accpt your answer at this time!

Comment: No problem, the ticket to Canada will do then :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tested working for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://www.aircanada.com/en/'
browser.get(url)

input_field = browser.find_element_by_id('departure1')

browser.execute_script("arguments[0].value = ''", input_field)
input_field.send_keys('12/04/2014')
input_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: thanks upvoted but realizing which one to be accepted either yours or of barak manos

Comment: At times like these, you wish you had multiple answer accept feature?!;)

Comment: @Amith yes, i agree with you.

Comment: @neha - well both are good,so i had to delete mine. Why don't you try flipping a coin?:)

Comment: @Amith I really flipped  a coin honestly once, and user1177636 won!

Comment: It was meant to be i guess! happy Testing:)

Answer (score 5):

The `clear()` function is for this purpose.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://www.aircanada.com/en/'
browser.get(url)

dep_date = browser.find_element_by_id('departure1')
dep_date.clear()
dep_date.send_keys('28/03/2014')
```

Haven't tested but this should do what you wanted, in a more 'Pythonic' way.

Comment: Either this is broken or I'm misusing it. When I run `clear()` on a element it returns `None` and I can't send it new keys with `send_keys()`

Answer (score 3):

A couple of errors in your code:

- The date format is wrong (should be `DD/MM/YYYY`, and not `YYYY-MM-DD`).
- You need to delete the `DD/MM/YYYY` using 10 clicks on the *backspace* key.

Here is the fix:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://www.aircanada.com/en/'
browser.get(url)
departure1 = browser.find_element_by_id('departure1')
departure1.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE*10)
departure1.send_keys('21/03/2014')
departure2 = browser.find_element_by_id('departure2')
departure2.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE*10)
departure2.send_keys('22/03/2014')
```

Comment: @Amith: Thanks, I tested it, and it does.